# Checking for visibility with Capybara

Tags: rspec, capybara

I'm trying to write some RSpec to verify if a `div` is visible or not under defined circumstances but I'm having a hard time doing so.

In order to figure out how to make it work (in the real code I have a piece of JS that add the CSS class) I have hard-coded everything but still the visibility check is not working.

The code looks like

```
#CSS
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.visible {
  display: block;
}


#HTML
<div id="blah" class="hidden">blah</div>


#RSpec
scenario 'blah blah' do
  expect(find('#blah').visible?).to be false
end
```

An I get

```
Failure/Error: expect(find('#blah').visible?).to be false

       expected false
            got true
```

UPDATE1:  I'm using the Selenium webdriver.

```
#rails_helper
...
require 'selenium-webdriver'
...
```

UPDATE2: updated HTML

Am I missing anything here?
How can I check for visibility?

Thanks (politeness first)

Answer (score 4):

Since it seems like you're starting out with Capybara, I'm guessing you're using the rack-test driver.  The rack-test driver is very basic and doesn't process most CSS.  The only things it will process as far as visibility goes are the `hidden` attribute and inline `display: none` style .  If you use one of the more advanced drivers (selenium, poltergeist, capybara-webkit) then CSS gets fully processed.

The next thing to note is that (by default) Capybara will only find visible elements, so `find('#blah')` will either return a visible element or raise a Capybara::ElementNotFound exception.  If you need to assert for the existence/non-existence of an element on a page you could do something like

```
expect(page).to have_css('#blah') #check the element exists and is visible
expect(page).not_to have_css('#blah') #check element doesn't exist or is non-visible
```

Another option would be to use the `visible` option to change the default behavior of only finding visible elements, although this would generally be a non-necessary test since from the users perspective it doesn't matter whether the element exists or not if it's not visible (hence Capybaras default behavior of only finding visible elements).

```
expect(page).to have_css('#blah', visible: :hidden) # check but the element exists but is non-visible
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried your latest suggestion but when I run it I get `expected to find css "#blah" but there were no matches.`. I have also tried with `Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false` but I get the same result. See also UPDATE1.

Comment: @macsig - 1st - don't use ignore_hidden_elements = false when testing apps you'll regret it later. 2nd - just because you've required selenium-webdriver doesn't mean you're using the selenium driver - unless you've tagged your tests with `js: true`  metadata, or set `Capybara.default_driver = :selenium` you're still using rack-test.  You can tell because a browser won't be opening that runs your tests when using rack-test. - 3rd - if your are using selenium the first one would give that error because the element is hidden so you'll have to be more specific as to which suggestion you tried

Comment: Additionally a div would need some content or have dimensions set to be considered visible